# Caulking around base of toilet

Tags: toilet, caulking

I just remodeled my bathroom by the master bedroom and the toilet needed to be shimmed since the tile around the flange was a bit higher than where the toilet bowl ends.  After shimming there is a slight gap exposing beneath the toilet. I attempted caulking it on a whim but it did not look good.

How do you caulk around the base of the toilet and make it look good? a.k.a. how to make the caulk even and smooth.  I tried a spoon as well,  that did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I re-caulked my tub I used painters tape on both the tub and the wall with a gap in-between.  I then caulked the space between the two pieces of tape, smoothed out with a plastic spoon and then pulled the tape away.
The lines were straight and even.

I imagine you can do the same with your toilet, put tape on the floor then slightly above the bottom edge of your toilet, fill the gap and then remove the tape.

Answer (score 4):

Two words: clear silicone.

You can match any toilet to any floor effortlessly if you use the clear stuff. It transmits the colors of the toilet and the floor and doesn't create an ugly, wavy visual line.

I usually use a finger if I'm dealing with a larger gap. Silicone wipes off skin cleanly enough that it's not a problem. Try to fill the void fairly flatly so you're not pulling a lot of caulk along as you tool it out. Err on the side of too little.

Note: While I don't agree that toilets should be left completely uncaulked to show failure of the wax ring seal, I do think it's wise to leave the back portion open for that reason. It's often difficult to reach that area with a caulking gun anyway.

Comment: While I like the simplicity of the clear caulk,  im not really sure it's going to look the way I want it to.  Im not discounting the idea yet... im going to go find some pictures.

Comment: That's the point... it shouldn't *look* like anything but a toilet sitting on a floor.

Comment: I'll check it out and if I end up going with it I will mark your as the answer.  Thanks man.

Comment: I decided against it due to the fact that I want it to look like the toilet goes to the floor whereas the clear stuff will still look like a gap.

Comment: It should be clear, smell not the best, and not be washable in any way with water (while wet).  And clear so you can add plenty and still have it look good no matter the circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

When my toilet wasn't caulked, small roaches crawled from beneath the toilet into my clean bathroom. The toilet sits on ceramic tiles. I do not like sewer roaches in my bathroom, even if they are baby-sized. I vote, caulk the toilet.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT CAULK AROUND THE BASE OF YOUR TOILET. When (not if) the wax seal is compromised you need to know right away. Caulking the base will hide the condition until you are made aware by other catastrophic means. Don't do it, I have replaced dozens of toilets and seen many damaged floors due to hidden leaks.

Comment: You are supposed to leave the back of the toilet uncaulked for that very reason.

Comment: I agree, but many plumbing inspectors here will fail you if you don't caulk the toilet to the floor.